# Speed up hide/unhide column

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I would like to hide and unhide the column depending upon the value on row 1. Is there any way to speed this up? It's slower than I'd like.

```
Sub Hide_Column()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("C9").Value = 100
    Range("C10").Value = 100
    ' Unhide_Column Macro
    Columns("D:XFD").Select
    Range("XFD1").Activate
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    ' Hide_Columns Macro
    Range("D1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 2).Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `Select` makes it slow.

Please refer to: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Hide_Column()
    Dim c As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("C9").Value = 100
    Range("C10").Value = 100
    ' Unhide_Column Macro
    Columns("D:XFD").Hidden = False
    ' Hide_Columns Macro
    Set c = Range(Range("D1"), Range("D1").End(xlToRight)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 2)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```